# Can I distinguish between 0 and False?

Tags: python

I have a function in a code which returns me a certain position of a list, if some conditions are True.
And in the next function, I use this position.
So the returned position can be 0.
But if the conditions are not true, the function shall return False.
The next function asks whether "position == false", but as I just read, it interprets it as 0.

Can I distinguish between 0 and False?
And actually I don't want to use some number like -123456 to be returned, because I want to publish the code in my thesis.

Comment: As you can see, it's not such a good idea to use `False` for this purpose. Why don't you use `None` instead?

Comment: You *can*, but you probably shouldn't. Your function should raise an exception  rather than return a special sentinel that you need to explicitly distinguish from a valid index.

Comment: `> I don't want to use some number like -123456` - actually it is a good practice to return negative value (say, -1) if something was not found. At least it is used in .NET for a years, during its inception. Because indexes can't be negative (we are not talking about ranges).

Comment: "Because indexes can't be negative" That's exactly why it's *not* a good idea for a function that purports to return an index to return a negative value. You still have to check to avoid using a possibly invalid index (and in Python, a negative number is *not* necessarily an invalid index in the first place).

Comment: So, is `None` better than `-1` in a function with name like `find_index(filter_parameters...)`? - I believe it's not.

Comment: Yes, it absolutely is, because `[1,2,3][-1]` can silently succeed where `[1,2,3][None]` cannot.

Comment: Returning a negative integer does not seem too far off though given that built-in `"abc".find("d")` *does* return `-1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use special sentinel values to signal an error. If your function is supposed to return an index, make sure every value it returns *is* a valid index, and raise an exception to indicate a problem.

```
def foo() -> int:
    if <condition>:
        return computed_index()
    raise ValueError("No valid index")


try:
    position = foo()
except ValueError:
    # do whatever position == False was supposed to do
```

The alternative is to return a value that absolutely cannot be a valid index, and exists precisely to indicate the *lack* of a some other value: `None`.

```
def foo() -> int | None:
    if <condition>:
        return computed_index()

if (position := foo()) is None:
    handle error

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, like this:

```
0 == False # True
# however...
0 is False # False
```